# Cucumber same sentence different scenarios

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm working with a java Spring Boot 2 application on which I'm using cucumber and gherkin.

I'm not understanding how to manage the situations in which the same sentence represents a different action.

Given the following sentence

```
And the user fills the field email with 'myEmail@email.com'
```

The problem is that the field "email" is in the signUp page and in the signIn page.

When I write the implementation of this sentence how can I understand whether I need to fill the signUp page or signIn page?

Searching on google I'm not finding anything about that, maybe there're some anti-pattern in my sentence?

Are there some real examples, in order to understand better?

Thank you

Comment: Are the two pages used in different scenarios? Then you might keep the state between the steps. https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with,

```
And the user fills the field email with 'myEmail@email.com' on the 'signUp' page

And the user fills the field email with 'myEmail@email.com' on the 'signIn' page'
```

?

Comment: In order to have two different actions, you'll need to define two different steps. The examples by @MikeJRamsey56 are one way to solve this. There might be other ways that better suit your domain / what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The anti-pattern is that you are using your feature/scenarios to describe HOW you are doing something rather than having you feature/scenarios describe WHAT you are doing and WHY its important. You can push the details of HOW you do things into the bodies of step definitions, or better yet into helper methods that step definitions can call.

From your example you clearly have two scenarios

- user signs up (I prefer to use 'register' here)
- user signs in

So

```
Scenario: Sign up
  When I sign up
  Then I should be signed up

Scenario: Sign in
  When I sign in
  Then I should be signed in
```

And down the stack some helper method (mine are in Ruby)

```
def sign_up(new_user: )
  visit sign_up_page
  fill_in :email, with new_user.email
  fill_in :password, with new_user.password
  fill_in :confirmation, with new_user.password
  ...
  submit_form
end

def sign_in(user: )
  visit sign_in_page
  fill_in :email, with user.email
  fill_in :password, with user.password
  submit_form
end
```

Working this way you have a clear differentiation between sign_in and sign_up and no possibility of using the wrong step definition.